# Angularjs directive close on click outside using event stopPropagation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I am using a directive to make a dialog close when clicked outside of it.

I had to use event.stopPropagation so that the open button will not close it.
It works but i feel that using stopPropagation is not the right way,
is there a better way of doing this ?
or using stopPropagation is ok ?

I want the dialog to open with a button or **programmaticaly**. and i want it to close when clicked outside of it.

Here is my full working example [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7IPdRMYa8vOwzEBtUEmi?p=preview)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.dialogOpen = false;

  $scope.closeDialog = function() {
    console.log('closing');
    $scope.dialogOpen = false;
  };

  $scope.openDialog = function($event) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('opening');
    $scope.dialogOpen = true;
  };
}]);

myApp.directive('myDialog', ['$document', function($document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      'close': '&'
    },
    template: "<div ng-transclude></div>",
    link: function(scope, element) {
      var handler = function(event) {
        if (!element[0].contains(event.target)) {
          console.log('click outside');
          scope.$apply(scope.close());
        }
      };

      console.log('creating handler');
      $document.on('click', handler);

      scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        $document.off('click', handler);
      });

    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: it should be `scope.$apply(scope.close);` instead of `scope.$apply(scope.close());` other code seems fine on a glance